# Missing 1 required positional argument: 'its'

Tags: python

when executing this code, an error occurs: TypeError: j1() missing 1 required positional argument: 'its'

```
            elif id == 526891231 and "/remove" in msg:
                #try:
                    a = msg.split(' ')
                    its = "remove"
                    commanda = a[0]
                    mode = a[1]
                    file = a[2]
                    path = a[3]
                    if commanda == '/remove':
                        if mode == 'jail':
                            j1(path + '/' + file, file, its)
                            j2(path + '/' + file, file, its)
                            j3(path + '/' + file, file, its)
                            update()
```

function description j1 ​​=

```
def j1(localpath, path, file, its):
    if its == 'upload':
        sftp.put(localpath, path)
        sender(xxx, 'JAIL-1: File uploaded successfully!' + ' [' + file + ' -> ' + path + ']')
        mode = 'JAIL-1'
        log(mode, file, path)
    if its == 'remove':
            sftp.remove(path)
            sender(526891231, 'JAIL-1: File deleted successfully!' + ' [' + path + ']')
            mode = 'JAIL-1'
            log(mode, file, path)
```

what is the problem?

Comment: Please include an [mcve] that shows the function causing the error, along with the stack trace of the error.

Comment: I added a description

Comment: `j1` defined as `j1(localpath, path, file, its)` with four positional arguments, and you call it by `j1(path + '/' + file, file, its)` which have only three arguments.